# Binding complex soap response to java bean

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a soap response in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:GetKgdErcInvoiceResponse xmlns:m="http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/SB_SERVICES/Invoice">
<response>
<result>RCVD</result>
<description>RCVD</description>
<Invoices xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:msgns="kz.eub.sb.wooppay.proxy.service" xmlns:ns0="http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/SB_SERVICES/Invoice" xmlns:ns2="kz.eub.sb.wooppay.proxy.service">
<Invoice Id="20160520112015039156">
<Header>
<Param Code="Address" Id="0">Кундакбаева Айман Жаксылыковна ул. Рыскулова, д. 5, кв. 50</Param>
<Param Code="formedDate" Id="1">2016-04-30 00:00:00</Param>
<Param Code="expireDate" Id="2">2016-06-01 00:00:00</Param>
</Header>
<Items>
<Item Id="1" Name="ТОО ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт электрическая энергия">
<Param Editable="true" Id="Amnt">1704.1</Param>
<Param Id="tariffType">FIXED</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMinValue">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMidValue">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMaxValue">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMinThreshold">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMaxThreshold">0</Param>
<Param Id="unit" />
<Param Id="counter" />
<Param Id="counterDate" />
<Param Id="lastCounter" />
<Param Id="lastCounterDate" />
<Param Id="debtInfo">задолженность 1704.10</Param>
</Item>
<Item Id="32" Name="ТОО ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт тепловая энергия и гвс">
<Param Editable="true" Id="Amnt">769.03</Param>
<Param Id="tariffType">FIXED</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMinValue">2</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMidValue">3</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMaxValue">4.8</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMinThreshold">6.4</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMaxThreshold">0</Param>
<Param Id="unit" />
<Param Id="counter" />
<Param Id="counterDate" />
<Param Id="lastCounter" />
<Param Id="lastCounterDate" />
<Param Id="debtInfo">задолженность 769.03</Param>
</Item>
<Item Id="65" Name="ТОО Қарағанды Су вода и канализация">
<Param Editable="true" Id="Amnt">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffType">FIXED</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMinValue">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMidValue">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMaxValue">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMinThreshold">0</Param>
<Param Id="tariffMaxThreshold">0</Param>
<Param Id="unit" />
<Param Id="counter" />
<Param Id="counterDate" />
<Param Id="lastCounter" />
<Param Id="lastCounterDate" />
<Param Id="debtInfo">задолженность 0.00</Param>
</Item>
</Items>
<Summary>
<Amount Currency="KZT">2473.13</Amount>
</Summary>
</Invoice>
</Invoices>
</response>
</m:GetKgdErcInvoiceResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is there any good way to bind it to a bean like:

```
public class Invoice {
    String Id;
    String address;
    Date formedDate;
    Date expireDate;
    List<InvoiceItem> items;
    String currency;
    BigDecimal amount;
}
```

I've tried different ways with JAXB, but still no luck for me. I wonder if there is a better way than to parse it manually.

### **Edited.**

I've managed to get the SOAP body. But I couldn't bind GetKgdErcInvoiceResponse to the Invoice class. Is it possible using JAXB annotations? The perfect solution to me would be something like:

```
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(soapStr.getBytes()));
Unmarshaller unmarshallerSoap = JAXBContext.newInstance(Invoice.class).createUnmarshaller();
Invoice invoice = (Invoice) unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
```

By the way, I am getting an error while trying to bind SOAP body:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/SB_SERVICES/Invoice", local:"GetKgdErcInvoiceResponse"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Why expected elements are none?

Comment: Do you want to parse RAW SOAP response, or you just need to parse XML in the soap body?

Comment: I need to parse XML.

Comment: Have a look at the [JAXB Users Guide](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.11/docs/ch03.html) there are examples how to annotate Java Classes with JAXB Annotationons and how to unmarshall xml files

Comment: I've read the docs and tried out some simple xml. But this one is more complex. Is it possible to bind xml attribute value (i.e. "Address") to a class field?

Comment: There are also "complex" examples. You need annotations like `@XmlType` or `@XmlAttribute` to map your class to the xml structure. Also have a look at things like the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. 
One way is you should use a SOAP library to separate SOAP Header and SOAP body.
Once you have the response from the body, then you can use JAXB. I personally prefer apache common digester for the same.

If you want to work with the SOAP stream, a SAX parser would also do the trick.

Comment: I've added an edit related to your answer. Can you provide some sample with JAXB annotations?